# UserDefaults UIButton States loads incorrectly sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, userdefaults

I am having trouble with UserDefaults loading the correct boolean value for a button state. Well I have two buttons within the same TableViewCell. One button is called "OzButton" and the other called "mLButton".  Although I written the code and it has been working so far, sometimes there will be rare cases when I tap, for example, the mL button and then after relaunching the app, it would highlight the OzButton instead of the mL Button even though I already tapped it. I am creating the UIButtons and its own targets programmatically. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I will attach an image of the View Controller for visual purposes.

[View Controller Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJ0Rk.jpg)

I have been stuck on this for a while...

I am not sure what I am doing wrong... please help!

```
var didOzTapped = Bool()
let conversionDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

lazy var ozButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("oz", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .clear
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOzTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

lazy var mlButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("mL", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.contentMode = .center
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "SFProDisplay-Bold", size: 16)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleMLTap), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    checkForConversionDefaults()
}

@objc func handleOzTap() {
    didOzTapped = true

    mlButton.isSelected = !didOzTapped

    ozButton.isEnabled = false

    mlButton.isEnabled = true

    ozButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    mlButton.backgroundColor = .white

    conversionDefaults.set(didOzTapped, forKey: "tapTheOz")        
}

@objc func handleMLTap() {

    didOzTapped = false

    ozButton.isSelected = didOzTapped

    ozButton.isEnabled = true

    mlButton.isEnabled = false

    mlButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    ozButton.backgroundColor = .white

    conversionDefaults.set(didOzTapped, forKey: "tapTheOz")
}

fileprivate func checkForConversionDefaults() {

    if conversionDefaults.bool(forKey: "tapTheOz") {
        print("ConversionDefaults: true")

        ozButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        mlButton.backgroundColor = .white

    } else {
        print("ConversionDefaults: false")

        mlButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        ozButton.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let profileCell = ProfileCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:

    case 1:
// some code 

    case 2:            
        profileCell.cellView.addSubview(measurementLabel)
        measurementUnitLabel.anchor(top: profileCell.cellView.topAnchor, leading: profileCell.cellView.leadingAnchor, bottom: .none, trailing: profileCell.cellView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 5, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20))

// created a stackView called ozMilButtonStackView (ozButton and mLButton)
 profileCell.cellView.addSubview(ozMilButtonStackView)
        ozMilButtonStackView.anchor(top: measurementUnitLabel.bottomAnchor, leading: profileCell.cellView.leadingAnchor, bottom: profileCell.cellView.bottomAnchor, trailing: profileCell.cellView.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 10, right: 100))

    default:
        break
    }

    return profileCell
}
```

Comment: add this `conversionDefaults.synchronize()` after setting the value in UserDefaults

Comment: It is probably a defaults issue on the simulator. A `UISegmentedControl` night work better than two buttons. You should also test for accessibility if this is a real app; make sure that people with various vision impairments can tell which button is selected. Same for voice over

Comment: I appreciate your response Paulw11! Using on a real device it has been consistent and correct... so far. When running on simulators, it does the job but then again on those rare times, UserDefaults would be weird on loading the correct value... I will definitely try out the UISegmentedControl way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after experimenting. It looks like it was a simulator issue (I was using the iPhone X sim). Running on a real device had no problem saving and updating UserDefaults.

I used another simulator (iPhone 6s Plus) and still had NOT any issues with UserDefaults.

Not sure why the iPhone X Sim was giving me issues...

Answer (score -1):

add this `conversionDefaults.synchronize()` after setting the value in UserDefaults.

Code :

```
@objc func handleOzTap() {
    didOzTapped = true

    mlButton.isSelected = !didOzTapped

    ozButton.isEnabled = false

    mlButton.isEnabled = true

    ozButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    mlButton.backgroundColor = .white

    conversionDefaults.set(didOzTapped, forKey: "tapTheOz") 
    conversionDefaults.synchronize()

}
```

Comment: So I added that line of code. Re-run the app, it was set to the mL button and I tapped the Oz Button. Relaunching the app again and it was set back to the mL button... just fyi, I am using the iPhone X Simulator. I also try to use my real device it has been consistent and correct... but I have the fear if it will not stay consistent haha Not sure if this is a simulator issue.

Comment: @georrgee No idea, working fine in my simulator, can you check getting wrong value in UserDefaults or your UI is not configure correctly, means check UserDefaults in value in case of relaunch.

Comment: How weird... I have been using the debugger and print statements. Everything has the correct values... even when loading the controller, UserDefaults does contain the correct boolean... the again, sometimes it will set back to the previous state. I am not sure if my logic is incorrect... I have updated my question and code of how I am setting the UI. Is it bad practice to setup the views inside the cellForRow function or does it not matter?

Comment: add mlButton and ozButton inside the cell instead of adding.

Comment: I didn't downvote you SGDev. Perhaps someone else did

Comment: Well on the simulator it has been getting the same issue. So to answer your question... no. Not yet. I am continuing to test. Thank you for your response

Comment: last thing you can try is, just reset the simulator and then retest it. May it help you.

Comment: Oh okay, let me give that a shot. Will keep you updated